# IGeolocator's PositionChanged firing twice?

Tags: c#, events, xamarin, geolocation

#### Context

I'm developing a traffic management app using C# (Xamarin Forms) which requires a constant feed of the user's location.

#### Plugin

I'm using the Geolocator plugin by James Montemagno and the PositionChanged event on the IGeolocator interface seems to be triggering twice when a position change occurs.

#### Device

I'm currently debugging on an Android Emulator on Visual Studio Enterprise v15.5.3

#### Steps to reproduce the behaviour

*1) After instantiating the locator object:*

`IGeolocator locator = CrossGeolocator.Current`

*2) Some code for when the locator's PositionChanged is triggered:*

```
locator.PositionChanged += (sender,e) => {
// Testing its frequency
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Position Changed Triggered.");
}
```

*3) Start listening in an async `Task` function*

```
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
if(!locator.isListening)
    await locator.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 1, true);
```

4) Send coordinates via the emulator

#### Expected Results

The output window should display one message saying "Position Changed Triggered".

#### Actual Results

The output window has two identical messages printed, saying: "Position Changed Triggered".

Why is this happening? and how can I make it so that the event is ONLY triggered/handled ONCE for every time the position is actually changed.

#### What I've tried so far

- Googled the issue, not many identical situations found.
- Saw an explanation [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/842bf143-3740-49e3-bcaa-2d78bce6cc41/uwpgeolocator-report-interval-issue?forum=wpdevelop) which makes me believe it's the emulator has something to do with it, although I found the solution a bit ambiguous and am not sure what they're referring to with "Live/Pin Mode"
- Created a separate function and assigned the event to it, then removed it after calling my code. This **does** cause it to execute once, but it never executes again unless I reassign in. And if I do, sure enough the code will run for the second time, resulting in the same initial problem.
- Tried setting a boolean to check if it has already run once, but realised not long after how that's illogical.
- Tried to set a DateTime object to make sure no more than 1 event occurs in a given time frame; this was also no good.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried search in the Open/Closed issues in github

Comment: You could filter the events through Rx and use the DistinctUntilChanged method to ensure that even if you get more than one identical event, only one of them is passed through.

Comment: @Greggz Yes. If you looked, the latest issue you see posted on there is mine.

Comment: @Beederab Have you tried debbuging the same issue in a real device ?

Comment: It's likely that this issue wouldn't occur on a real device, I haven't had the chance to test it because we don't have an android phone available at this minute. It's needs to be done. But I'm asking more about the issue in the respective situation

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the location service might deliver a location event more than one time (more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)).

Even if the location service is not delivering the location event more than one time, usage and/or implementation of the API (Geolocator plugin) might cause reception of the location event more than one time from the API.

In the app you might check the location event properties (accuracy, location timestamp, order of event received, etc.). Use the "best" location event with "best" meaning preferred accuracy, most recent timestamp, or the first received location event if timestamp and accuracy are equal.

Comment: All accuracy etc. are set to the best, 100, and so on. Don't know why it's calling twice.